# Why my TextView is Scrolling in android?

Tags: android, textview

Why my TextView is Scrolling?

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rl_logo_header"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:text="Should my school be focused on -- Teaching and Learning come as words which are very closely related, But they convey very different meanings and can not be used interchangeably."
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

The content for this view could be text and may also contain HTML content. Hence I have set `autoLink` to `true`. The issue is, if either the `autoLink` or the `textIsSelectable` is `true`, then the textview starts to scroll similar to(`MovementMethod`) when its content is more than 3 lines. I am looking for a way to stop/disable this textview scrolling.

I tried to disable the scrolling using `setEnable(false)` for the text view, however all the links in the textview could not be clicked thereafter.

I think there has to be a straight forward way to achieve "non-scrollable textview" which may contain html content in them.

Answer (score 1):

`autoLink` controls whether the `TextView` will parse URLs and highlight them as such. It has nothing to do with rendering HTML.

Your `TextView` is scrolling because you've set `android:maxLines="3"`

Comment: It's scrolling to more than 3 lines. I need to prevent that.